# How can I align an image inside an ImageView to the bottom of the ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I want the drawable inside my ImageView to be shown aligned to the bottom (of the Imageview), and not centered.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Maybe this is too late, but even I ran into the same problem today and fixed it by using the following snippet.

All the alignment/scaling options are in the scaleType attribute.

Now, if you want to align the image with the beginning of the ImageView, use **`android:scaleType="fitStart"`**.

Similarly, **`android:scaleType="fitEnd"`** to align it with the bottom of the ImageView.

Comment: `fitStart` put image in top-left corner and `fitEnd` put in bottom-right corner. But what if you want image at `bottom-center`? For that Fresco provides custom scalType.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `ImageView` inside a `FrameLayout` and align using `android:layout_gravity` like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/img_select_profile" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have SVG you can open it in https://boxy-svg.com/app or any other online svg editor

Align Image Bottom.

[image]

Comment: For me, this helped. My svg had blank space at bottom. Without clipping that, none of other options worked.

Answer (score -2):

You'll have to set the weight of it to 1 or set its alignment to bottom.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. That method align the entire imageview to the bottom of LinearLayout. But i want that the drawable aligned to the bottom of the ImageView

Comment: OK, then how about setting android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in the XML instead?

Comment: I still have the same problem.